# How to run a process after page submit and before refresh

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am facing an issue in Oracle Apex (v5.1).

*I have a dialog page that opens up from the parent page on clicking of an icon. On Closing the dialog page,my parent page submits on the event 'Dialog Closed'
and a process which runs on the processing of the submit of parent page which seems to be not working. 
In that process,I have certain APEX_ITEMS whose values are being set on submit of the parent page. Is there any way to make the process run?*

**Extra Description** : I have an Interactive report which is fetched from a table say 'Temp', the report has links in some of the columns. 
When a user clicks the link he is redirected to a modal page (while setting an application variable say 'APP_VAR' to zero) and user can modify some data there.
In the modal page when user clicks 'Submit' button a process runs and updated the temp table and sets value of 'APP_VAR' to '1' 
and then page is refreshed. On the same modal page there is a Dynamic Action written on 'Page Load' with server side condition of 'APP_VAR' = '1',
this Dynamic Action closes the modal page with 'Close Dialog' action.

Now when the modal page is closed on parent page there is a dynamic action written on 'Dialog Closed' event which submits the parent page.
Also there is a process 'Update Parent' on condition of 'APP_VAR' ='1' which updates the 'temp' table with all the values from parent page (As user 
can change some of the values in the report.) and sets APP_VAR to 0.

All of this is done in order to keep the temp table updated with values from both pages.
But when modal page closes the parent page refreshes before 'Update Parent' process is completed leading to loss of any changes made in parent page.

How can I run 'Update Parent' before the page reloads? please keep in mind that before 'Update Parent' runs the report data needs to be submitted 
to session state in order to get the updated data.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1

Why do you not put the "Update Parent" process together with the dynamic action that submit the page? You would need two true actions in this dynamic action.

- The first one would execute its PL / SQL "Update Parent".
- The second would submit the page

or

Case 2

Or if you want to keep "Update Parent" in a process, just call it in the page submission (if necessary bind it to a button), put it in the correct order of execution (by setting the sequence number). In the dynamic action submitting the page define a button name for this submission (if necessary).

Example Case 2:

After closing the page I need to execute 3 processes. So, I link these 3 processes to a button, if necessary I put the conditions of the server.

After the submission:

```
10 - Process 1 (when I click the x button)
20 - Process 2 (when I click the x button)
30 - Process 3 (when I click the x button)
```

So I need to define in my dynamic action that submit page the name of the button associated with this submission (Fill in the "Request / Button Name" field).

*Hide this button.